# Prawn gem - Undefined Method 'position'

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

Using ruby 2.0.0, I am receiving the following error:

`undefined method 'position=' for #<Prawn::Table:0x007fa85cb72850> (NoMethodError)`

I've read several posts and 100% of them have pointed to adding this to your gem file and running `bundle update`:

`gem 'prawn', :git => "https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git", :ref => '8028ca0cd2'`

However, I still get the same error when I do this versus just using `gem 'prawn'`.

It's worth noting that my script worked perfectly fine on another machine in another environment, using the same gem file that only had `gem prawn` in it. I don't recall altering the other environment in any way to make it work, but it's possible that I did.

Any thoughts as to how I can get rid of this error?

Comment: how are you executing your script? what does `gem list prawn` say?

Comment: I am running it through a terminal window...

`gem list prawn` returns this:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

prawn (0.12.0)

Comment: What version of Prawn were you using in your old environment? you can output the version in your script to find out:

`puts Prawn::VERSION`

Comment: Also, what else is different about your environment? Were you using Ruby 2.0 previously?